# Basic rsyslog configuration

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I have program logging to Syslog and I want to split those messages out into separate files.

I want all messages generated by `MyApp` to go to `/var/log/my_app.log`, and anything `warn` or more serious to also go to `/var/log/my_app.err`.

I don't want the messages to end up in `/var/log/syslog`, as they do at the moment.

I have created a new rsyslog conf file `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-my_app.conf` in which I have:

```
if $programname == 'MyApp'
then
{
        if $pri <= 4
        then
        {
                /var/log/my_app.err
        }

        /var/log/my_app.log
        & stop
}
```

But it's only partially working. All messages end up in `my_app.log`, half of the messages still appear in `syslog` & nothing appears in `my_app.err`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
if $programname == 'MyApp'
then
{
    *.warning /var/log/my_app.err
    *.* /var/log/my_app.log
    & stop
}
```

Half of the problem was that my config file was getting loaded *after* another file which was logging my lines to `/var/log/syslog` before I had a chance to drop them, so I needed to change some file names to fix that.